# C# Regex how to get number

Tags: c#, regex

how to get phone number drom next files name

1. 09-33-07 [A 9312886109902] 'DN_9405~' (44,-0,0,0).wav
2. 08-47-51 [A 9309854699902] 'DN_9405~' (44,-0,0,0).wav
3. 07-58-49 [P 9160] 'DN_9405~' (44,-0,0,0) .wav

I need to get in one step

1. **931288610**
2. **930985469**
3. **9160**

now i use (\d{4,})[^(9902])] but on short numbers is wrong

Comment: Have you searched for "regex number in brackets"?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?  There are plenty of regex tutorials out there.  To get you started, you could start by trying to devise a regex to return the text between the square brackets.

Comment: I do not need all the numbers in brackets. now i use (\d{4,})[^(9902\])]  but on short numbers is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the below regex which matches upto 9902 or ] symbol,

```
(?<=[A-Z] ).*?(?=9902|])
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sL8vF1/2)

OR

```
(?<=[A-Z] )\d+?(?=9902|])
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sL8vF1/3)

Comment: just reminder: `.` will match not only number ,but also other non-newline , do you think it is good for `phone number`?

Comment: @Tim.Tang is this `(?<=[A-Z] )\d+?(?=9902|])` ok for you?

Answer (score 1):

phone number 's length is 4-9?

```
(?<=\[[a-zA-Z]+\s)\d{4,9}(?=\d*\])
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xE3eB6/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [Lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(?<=\[[A-Z] )\d+?(?=9902\]|\])
```

[online demo](http://regex101.com/r/qJ9cY9/6) and tested at [regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5b%5bA-Z%5d+)%5cd%2b%3f(%3f%3d9902%5d%7c%5d)&i=%0d%0a09-33-07+%5bA+9312886109902%5d+%27DN_9405%7e%27+(44%2c-0%2c0%2c0).wav%0d%0a08-47-51+%5bA+9309854699902%5d+%27DN_9405%7e%27+(44%2c-0%2c0%2c0).wav%0d%0a07-58-49+%5bP+9160%5d+%27DN_9405%7e%27+(44%2c-0%2c0%2c0)+.wav%0d%0a)

Pattern explanation:

```
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
    [[A-Z]                   any character of: '[', 'A' to 'Z'

  )                        end of look-behind
  \d+?                     digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
    9902]                    '9902]'
   |                        OR
    ]                        ']'
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: `[` is keyword in Regex for `C#`, so we need to escape it as `\[` first

Comment: I don't think so as per the testing site.

Comment: Try deleting the opening `[`, or the letter, from the input, not the pattern, and you'll still get a match. You need to escape the first `[` in the pattern.

Comment: @Rawling OK updated but don't know why regex sites doesn't claim for it

Comment: I also tried it on the regex site. Just because your pattern matches the input doesn't mean it doesn't match other, incorrect input.

Comment: @Rawling thanks I got it. I looked at explanation part where it says to match `[`.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for square bracket, than letter, than space, than 1+ digits, than quare bracket. So the regular expression is: `[\[][A-Z].\d+[\]]`

But because you want to ezxtract only 1+ digits (number) you need to group them using `()`, so regex is `[\[][A-Z].(\d+)[\]]`

Then the rest of the code is simple:

```
Regex regexp = new Regex("[\[][A-Z].(\d+)[\]]");
foreach(var mc in qariRegex.Matches(yourstring))
{
    Console.Writeln(mc[0].Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: Just to note that the escaping slashes in your first and last character classes are unnecessary. `[` has no special meaning in a character class, and `]` does not need escaping if it is the first character in the class.